# Assistance finding limit of a term

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find a limit of some term, which I know exists, but cannot seem to compute it properly for some reason (I've checked for mistakes along the way three times now, and there aren't any, so it seems that I'm just missing something related to limit manipulations):

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t} \bigg(\lim_{l\to 0} \frac{1}{l}\bigg[ \frac{4(1+t+l)(t+l)+3(1+3l)(1+l)}{(1+t+l)(1+3l)-6t(t+l)} - \frac{4t(1+t)+3}{1+t-6t^2}\bigg]-4\bigg)$$

The closest I got was when I tried using the limit  over $l$ on the denominator of the long term to get the same denominator as in the term on the right (they're identical when $l \to 0$) but that didn't get me very far. I somehow always end up with terms that are some function of $t$ (or a constant) divided by $l$, and so the limit for those terms doesn't exist.

**EDIT:**

Just realised I forgot to add the $\frac{1}{l}$ (added before the first square bracket) and the $-4$ added before the last curved bracket.

What am I missing?

Comment: substitute $l'=\frac{1}{l}$ to transform the limit to $l'\to\pm\infty$ of a certain fraction of polynomials, then you can just look at the limit of the fraction of terms with highest exponent (you will probably have to make it so both fractions have the same denominator). This lets you solve inner limit, the outer limit is done in the same way. This is a lot of calculating and I recomment doing this with the computer. You get that the inner limit is $\frac{-4-17t+92t^2+36t^3}{-1-2t+11t^2+12t^3-36t^4}$ and the whole limit equals $9$.